# The house ______ roof is yellow is my grandparents' (relative clause, of which VS whose)

Tags: relative-clauses

```
The house ______ roof is yellow is my grandparents'
```

I'm studying relative cluase of English and wondering what is the correct answer for that particular question.

At first I thought it would be `of which` because then the original sentences would be:

```
1. The house is my grandparents'
2. Roof of the house is yellow.
```

But I realised that the sentence #2 lacks the proper article, `the`, so I think the answer might be `whose`. 
However, as of my knowledge `whose` is for people (or animals at best) and it is rarely used for things or objects.

So which one should be the answer? Or it is possible that the both are okay and natural? 
I want it to be grammatically correct but I'd also like to know which one is more 'natural'. Thanks!

Comment: Who told you that **whose** is only used with people? That's just not true.

Comment: @CookieMonster As I said, I thought they are usually used with people, with rare occations where they are used with things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The house **whose** roof is yellow is my grandparents'.

*Whose* is used for people, but it is also the possessive case of *which* (used for objects).

Since we're using possessive cases, the formulation of the answer is

> The house is my grandparents'.
>
> The house has a yellow roof.

where the *roof* belongs to the house.

Now, you would write accordingly:

> The house **that** has a yellow roof is my grandparents'.
>
> The house **which** has a yellow roof is my grandparents'.

*Of which* doesn't work because *of* can't be placed anywhere else in the sentence. An example of *of which* used correctly:

> The computers **of which** there are few are at the back of the store.
>
> The computers **which** there are few **of** are at the back of the store.

---

As  mentioned in the comments, *whose* can be used for both people and things, and if you believe otherwise, you will make mistakes in the future  by using the wrong possessive.

If you're looking for something more natural, your best bet is:

> The house **with** the yellow roof **belongs** to my grandparents.